# IDL to Matlab code translation

Tags: matlab, formula, binomial-theorem

I have this piece of code written in IDL

```
for i=n-1,0,-1 do y = TEMPORARY(y) * x + c[i]
```

I want to understand how can I implement in Matlab. The description says tha this function returns

```
c[0] + c[1]*x + c[2]*x^2 + ...
```

I tried manually doing this in Matlab but my answer is different from the one using IDL. Thank you in advance.

**Edit:**

I have added the code here in my third edit, to make it a bit shorter.

**Edit 2:**

**Edit 3:**
This is the piece of code in my `SEDfinal.m` that is giving me the problem

```
wl_uvb = [3030.8; 3031.0; 3031.2; 3031.4; 3031.6; 3031.8; 3032.0; 3032.2; 3032.4; 3032.6; 3032.8; 3033.0; 3033.2; 3033.4];
f_uvb = [0.3539; 0.2284; 0.1788; 0.4813; 0.1783; -0.2679; 0.2853; 0.5093; -0.1204; 0.2237; 0.1706; -0.2036; 0.1912; 0.2150];
uvbflux_o1 = ccm_unred(wl_uvb,f_uvb,0.1,3.1);
```

What `ccm_unred` does is,

```
x = 10000./wl_uvb;
npts = length(x);
a = zeros(npts,1);
b = zeros(npts,1);
```

and than

```
good = find(1.1 <= x & x < 3.3);
ngood = length(good);

if ngood > 0
    y = x(good) - 1.82;
    c1 = [1, 0.104, -0.609, 0.701, 1.137, -1.718, -0.827, 1.647, -0.505];
    c2 = [0, 1.952, 2.908, -3.989, -7.985, 11.102, 5.491, -10.805, 3.347];

    a(good) = polyIDL(y, c1);
    b(good) = polyIDL(y, c2);
end
```

This is where the problem begins. The IDL `poly` function is

```
% OUTPUTS:
%   POLY returns a result equal to:
%        C[0] + c[1] * X + c[2]*x^2 + ...

FUNCTION POLY,X,C
    compile_opt idl2
    on_error,2
    N = N_ELEMENTS(C)-1    ;Find degree of polynomial
    % Special case for N=0. Be sure to return a result of the
    % same type and array dimensions as X.
    if (n eq 0) then $
        return, x*0 + c[0]
    Y = c[n]
    for i=n-1,0,-1 do y = TEMPORARY(y) * x + c[i]
    return,y
end
```

and what I'm doing in matlab

```
function y = polyIDL(x,c)
    n = length(c) - 1;
    if n == 0
        y = x*0 + c(1);
    end
    % c(1) + c(2)*x + c(3)*x^2 + c(4)*x^3 + c(5)*x^4 + c(6)*x^5 + c(7)*x^6 +
    % c(8)*x^7 + c(9) * x^8
    if n > 0
        for i=1:n
            z(i) = c(i).*x(i).^(i-1);
        end
    end
    y = z(i);
end
```

I did change the code in matlab, as now I'm dealing with more values. And the results are SO different

```
matlab: All values are [n]*10^-05
    0.0807, 0.0521, 0.0408, 0.1097, 0.0406, -0.0611, 0.0650, 0.1161, -0.0274, 0.0510, 0.0389, -0.0464, 0.0436, 0.0490
idl:
    0.59040940, 0.38102922, 0.29827669, 0.80289233, 0.29742825, -0.44688237, 0.47589615, 0.84951931, -0.20082417, 0.37311712, 0.28454325, -0.33957571, 0.31888679, 0.35857213
```

Comment: Show what you've tried! Read how to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Why would you test for `length(x) < length(c)`? Isn't `x` always a scalar?

Comment: Not in my case, X here represents a vector for which I have a fixed amount of `c`

Comment: @beaker I'll post the requirements ASAP

Comment: @beaker the `X` and `C` passed to polyIDL are the `y` and `c1` from where I wrote "and than" same goes in the `poly` function in `IDL`

Comment: @beaker okay let me try once more.

Comment: @beaker I have values in `wl_uvb` and `f_uvb` which are passed to `ccm_unred` as `wave` and `flux`. This should clear up `x = 10000./wl_uvb`. As for `y = x(good) - 1.82` I find values in `x` or `modified wl_uvb` which fall in range of `good` than I assign `y` to `x(good) - 1.82`. This `y` and the `c1` defined below is than passed to the funciton `polyIDL` which takes them in as `x` and `c` respectively. So in `polyIDL`, the `x` is `y = x(good) - 1.82` and `c` is `c1 = [1, 0.104, -0.609, 0.701, 1.137, -1.718, -0.827, 1.647, -0.505];`

Comment: @beaker I apologize, I noticed my error. The values I've given for `wl_uvb` are in the starting but it has 14.5K+ values for which this condition occurs for 14.3K values. I'll adjust the values right away.

Comment: @beaker I've double checked everything this time

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your results. Until you can provide a [mcve], I guess you're on your own.

Comment: @beaker thank you for your effort, I appreciate that.